# How to use multiple adb commands simultaneously in one device?

Tags: android, batch-file, automation, adb

I want to know if there is any way to use two adb commands in same line.
I am trying to make batch file for adb logcat and screen record.

Commands I am trying to use is

```
adb logcat -b main -b radio -b system -b events -v time > filename.log
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4
```

Comment: These commands work for me as long as its preceded with a `cd <platform-tool path>

Comment: @NekoMusume yea these works for me too but I want to use them simultaneously within one line commands..

Comment: Yes, for me it works when separated with `&` or `&&` but you need to be int he platform tools directory

Comment: hmm. for me I only get logcat file, there is no video [screeenrecord] file saved in sdcard. I've tried both & and &&.

Comment: Does the screenrecord work alone without the first command?

Comment: yes, both commands work fine alone

Comment: Huh... It may be an issue with the commands, try using `adb /? && adb /?` and see if it prints the help message twice

Comment: Is `adb` an executable or a batch file? if the latter, use `call adb ...`...